# How to set MaxLine 1.5 in Textview in android

Tags: java, android

**Is it possible to set the `android:maxLines` attribute to 1.5 in `TextView` ?**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"/>
```

Comment: According to Android reference `android:maxLines` must be an integer value. Could you provide some more details on which kind of effect do you want to obtain?

Comment: maxLines must be an Integer value. why do you need to set it 1.5?

Answer (score 0):

not possible according to developer.google as maxlines only takes integer as an input, you may follow the link provided

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines

Answer (score 0):

you can not give

```
android:maxLines="1.5"
```

It says validate resouce reference inside xml

It should be an integer value.

Read [android:maxLines](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLines) documentation.

> Makes the TextView be at most this many lines tall. When used on an
>   editable text, the inputType attribute's value must be combined with
>   the textMultiLine flag for the maxLines attribute to apply.
>
> Must be an integer value, such as "100".